# comparar dos vectores de calificaciones

Tags: bucle-for, condiciones, vectores

mi ejercicio es que tengo que comparar dos vectores de calificaciones distintas, por ejemplo
tengo vector 1 [8,9,4,6,5]  y luego esta el vector 2 [6,2,8,2,9]
y que al final del programa me diga si ambos vectores son iguales o son distintos

yo intente esto

//comparar dos vectores de calificaciones

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, m, iguales=0;

    cout<<"ingrese el numero de materias del alumno 1: "; cin>> n;
    cout<<"ingrese el numero de materias del alumno 2: "; cin>> m;

    int alumno1[n];
    int alumno2[m];

    for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ ){
        cout<<"para el alumno 1 ingrese el valor de sus calificaciones: "<< i<<endl;
        cin>>alumno1 [i];
    }

    for ( int k=0; k<m; k++){
        cout<<"para el alumno 2 ingrese el valor de sus calificaciones: "<< k<<endl;
        cin>>alumno2[k];
    }

    for ( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for ( int k=0; k<m; k++){
            if (alumno1 [i] = alumno2 [k]){
                iguales++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<" Las calificaciones que coinciden en ambos alumnos son:  "<< iguales;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo más sencillo es que partas de la premisa de que ambos vectores van a ser siempre iguales, luego comparas el tamaño de ambos vectores para ver si son iguales y que por último recorras a la vez ambos vectores comprobando el valor de los campos de la misma posición para ver si su contenido coinciden.

```
bool iguales = true;

if(n == m) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(alumno1[i] != alumno2[i]) {
            iguales = false;
        }
    }
} else {
    iguales = false;
}
```

Así si:

alumno1 = [8,9,4,6,5]; alumno2 = [8,9,4,6,5]; iguales = true

alumno1 = [8,9]; alumno2 = [8,9,4,6,5]; iguales = false

alumno1 = [8,9,4,6,5]; alumno2 = [8,4,3,6,5]; iguales = false